# How to upload in-memory zip file to S3-bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload an in-memory zip file to an S3-bucket (in order to avoid temporary files on my server).

Here's my code:

```
import zipfile
import io
zip_bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
zip_archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_bytes_io, mode='a',
                              compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zip_archive.writestr('test.txt', b'My string')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
zip_bytes_io.seek(0)  # So that bytes are read from beginning
s3_client.upload_fileobj(zip_bytes_io, test_bucket, 'test.zip')
```

When I run the above code, it does upload the file to an S3 bucket. However when I download the file, I am unable to unzip it. I get the error :"Error 1 - operation not permitted."

I assume this is because I'm not uploading the file correctly in the first place. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Not sure if there isn't another source of your error, but the archive you're uploading is incomplete. After having done `writestr()` (and your archive being complete) you have to first `zip_archive.close()`. You can try `tell()` on the `zip_bytes_io` to see the difference before and after `close()`.

Comment: @OndrejK.

I think:
`s3_client.upload_fileobj(zip_bytes_io, test_bucket, 'test.zip')`
closes the file by default? 

If I add the line
`zip_archive.close()`
The exception is `{ValueError}I/O operation on closed file.` is thrown.

Comment: It would appear that `zip_archive.close()` actually also closed `zip_bytes_io`, but that is not a behavior I could reproduce. Could you perhaps show the full backtrace of the recent failure? But as mentioned, it just occurred to me. It might not be related at all.

Comment: Would it be possible to write the zip to a tempfile and then use [upload_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html) to get it uploaded -- sending tempfileobj.name as the name of the file, before closing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking for `Error 1 - operation not permitted.` error online, looks like it might be a `Mac-os` opening a zip file issue?

Try to open the file differently?

Comment: Ahh yes, you are correct. All I had to do was use this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12
instead of the Mac default tool, `Archive Utility` to unzip the file and it worked.